# Force Powershell script to continue when prompted

Tags: powershell

I am creating a Powershell script that uses the command `net share $ShareName $ServerName /delete` to stop sharing a folder. The problem is, if there are open files, it will pause and require the user to press `Y` to continue. I plan on scheduling this script to run overnight (users shouldn't be leaving stuff open overnight) and would like the script to continue automatically no matter what.

Is there a way to send input to the console to imitate pressing the key, or is there some way to specify in the command to force the delete?

Comment: Just add switch `/yes` to command.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```psh
echo y|net share $ShareName $ServerName /delete
```

If you're worried about multiple prompts, just do more `y`s, like `echo yyyyyy|`.

Comment: Yeah that's probably better for this case. I'll leave this here because it can be useful for other commands that don't have a built-in switch for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the operation:

```
$share = Get-WmiObject -Computer $ServerName -Class Win32_Share -Filter "Name='$ShareName'"
$share.Delete()
```

Quoting from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The **Delete** WMI class method deletes a share name from a server's list of shared resources, disconnecting connections to the shared resource.

Answer (score 0):

```
net share $ShareName $ServerName /delete /yes
```